# Advanced PHP upload form

Tags: php, mysql, forms, upload, insert

MySQL Table looks like this:
[image]

Here's the code of the output:

```
<li>
    <a class="thumb" href="library/<?php echo $row2['projectname']; ?>/<?php echo $row2['projectrecordnum']; ?>.<?php echo $row2['projectformat']; ?>" title="<?php echo $row2['projectrecordtitle']; ?>">
        <img src="library/<?php echo $row2['projectname']; ?>/thumbs/<?php echo $row2['projectrecordnum']; ?>.<?php echo $row2['projectformat']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $row2['projectrecordtitle']; ?>" />
    </a>
    <div class="caption">
        <div class="image-title"><?php echo $row2['projectrecordtitle']; ?></div>
        <div class="image-desc"><?php echo $row2['projectrecorddesc']; ?></div>
        <div class="download">
            <a href="library/<?php echo $row2['projectname']; ?>/<?php echo $row2['projectrecordnum']; ?>.<?php echo $row2['projectformat']; ?>" target="_blank">Download Original</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</li>
```

Here's how the output looks:

```
<li>

    <a class="thumb" href="library/ultima/2.jpg" title="Timbo DISPLACED">

        <img src="library/ultima/thumbs/2.jpg" alt="Timbo DISPLACED" />

    </a>

    <div class="caption">

        <div class="image-title">Timbo DISPLACED</div>

        <div class="image-desc">Made in 3ds Max, background, color and lens flare from Photoshop</div>

        <div class="download">

            <a href="library/ultima/2.jpg" target="_blank">Download Original</a>

        </div>

    </div>

</li>
```

My problem is that I can't find a way to make form, that will create a number of fields,  that user wants; then uploads and writes each file info into a mysql db (remember that the amount of files isn't definite).

Comment: What exactly is your problem? How does your `form` look like?

Comment: Currently it just carries main info like project name, project display name, project format, project comment, project info

Comment: So you want a system that will create an unknown quantity/arbitrary content set of form fields and handle stuffing those who-knows-what fields into a database?

Answer (score 1):

It's not really a specific question, however I'll try to provide you a starting point.

I assume you don't have a form yet...

**FYI**: don't mind to escape your output with `htmlentities()` or something similar!

1) I used dummy data, but you can replace this with your associative DB result set:

```
$rows = array(
    array(  'projectname' => 'ultima',
            'projectrecordnum' => '1',
            'projectrecordtitle' => 'The ball of destruction'),
    array(  'projectname' => 'ultima',
            'projectrecordnum' => '2',
            'projectrecordtitle' => 'Timbo DISPLACED'),
    array(  'projectname' => 'ultima',
            'projectrecordnum' => '3',
            'projectrecordtitle' => 'Exposure')
);
```

2) I created a simple HTML form looping by PHP on results:

```
<form method="post" action="#">
<?php foreach( $rows as $row ) { ?>
    <div class="caption">
        <div class="">
            <input type="text" name="projectname[]" value="<?php echo $row['projectname']; ?>">
        </div>
        <div class="">
            <input type="text" name="projectrecordnum[]" value="<?php echo $row['projectrecordnum']; ?>">
        </div>
        <div class="">
            <input type="text" name="projectrecordtitle[]" value="<?php echo $row['projectrecordtitle']; ?>">
        </div>
        <?php /* and so more fields ... */ ?>
    </div>
    <hr />
<?php } ?>
    <input type="submit" name="send" value="send" />
</form>
```

3) And in the `action` you can rebuild your `$rows` array:

```
if( isset($_REQUEST['send']) ) {
    $rows  = array();
    for( $i = 0; $i < count( $_POST['projectname'] ); $i++) {
        $row = array(
            'projectname' => $_POST['projectname'][$i],
            'projectrecordnum' => $_POST['projectrecordnum'][$i],
            'projectrecordtitle' => $_POST['projectrecordtitle'][$i],
        );
        if( ! empty( $_POST['projectname'][$i] ) ) { 
            array_push( $rows, $row );
        }
        unset($row);
    }

    // Your data array...
    print '<pre>'. print_r($rows, true) . '</pre>';
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply! It was quite useful. But you misunderstood me a bit. Number of fields should be defined by user, not by available rows. And

Comment: Mmm... and what happens if the user enters a field that does not match a column in the database table?

Comment: I found a solution - while loops!